# VBA code to Read Mails from - Other User's Inbox (Outlook Inbox)

Tags: vba, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outlook 2007 VBA to get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/outlook-2007-vba-to-get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Wwe need to open up other users inbox in Microsoft Outlook by File->Open->Other Users's Folder. Then we need to check for a mail. We have tried the below code

```
  Set olApp=CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
     Set olns=olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
     Set objFolder=olns.GetDefaultFolder(6)
     For each item1 in objFolder.Items 
             msgbox item1.subject     
     Next
```

But with this code we cant able to read mail from other users inbox since the `GetDefaultFolder` methods Parameter is 6 .. can somebody please help on this

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9076634/641067

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use something like the following:

```
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder
```

This should pop up a box to allow you to choose which folder you are trying to select to read from... However, this option requires some user interaction.

You also may want to try your code with the following change:

```
Set ObjFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(variable)
```

Where variable is the name of your default folder, ie for your inbox it is olFolderInbox