# Python Outlook: Read Inbox of additional mailbox

Tags: python, outlook, inbox

I'm using Outlook 2010 - and have my main mailbox: name@company.com

I have also added another mailbox to my profile: mb data proc

Both appear as top level folders within Outlook:

```
name@company.com
-Inbox
-Sent Items
-Deleted Items

mb data proc
-Inbox
-Sent Items
-Deleted Items
```

I cannot create a different profile for the additional mailbox. It has been added in the same profile.

How do I get a reference to the Inbox in the "mb data proc" mailbox?

This is the same problem as described here [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox) but this in VBS.

How to do in python?

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder=outlook.Folders("mb data proc")
msg=folder.Items
msgs=msg.GetLast()
print msgs
```

I tried this but I get this error:

```
       folder=outlook.Folders("mb data proc")
AttributeError: _Folders instance has no __call__ method
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar doubt and as I understand it the solution stated here is for Python 2.7

I will try to make it understandable regarding how to operate it using Python 3.+ versions.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("Mailbox Name")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()
print (msgs)
print (msgs.Subject)
```

Since _Folder is not callable, you need to use Folders.Item() method in Python 3+ to reference your mailbox.

Hope that was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution. I think the only part you missed was getting to the `"Inbox"` folder inside of `"mb data proc"`.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("mb data proc")
inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()
print msgs
```

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for other mailboxes or seperate PST files you have access to in outlook, try using the Store / Stores MAPI objects.

```
import win32com.client

for stor in win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Stores:
    print( stor.DisplayName)
```

PS *.Session* return the same reference as *.GetNamespace("MAPI")*

for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to access Additional Mail Boxes and read the Inbox from these Shared folders

> > > import win32com.client

```
>>> outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders

>>> folder = outlook(1)

>>> inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")

>>> message = inbox.Items

>>> messages = message.GetLast()

>>> body_content = messages.body

>>> print (body_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you Posts!
Here is a function I pulled together based on your Input, to read out the available Folders:

This is my first post, so I hope I copied the code in properly:

```
def check_shared(namespace,recip = None): 
    """Function takes two arguments:
        .) Names-Space: e.g.: 
            which is set in the following way: outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") and
        .) Recipient of an eventual shared account as string: e.g.: Shared e-Mail adress is "shared@shared.com"
            --> This is optional --> If not added, the standard-e-Mail is read out"""


    if recip is None:
        for i in range(1,100):                           
            try:
                inbox = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(i)     
                print ("%i %s" % (i,inbox))            
            except:
                #print ("%i does not work"%i)
                continue
    else:
        print('The folders from the following shared account will be printed: '+recip)
        tmpRecipient = outlook.CreateRecipient(recip)
        for i in range(1,100):                           
            try:
                inbox = namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(tmpRecipient, i)     
                print ("%i %s" % (i,inbox))            
            except:
                #print ("%i does not work"%i)
                continue
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you can use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder method.

Secondly, then line

`folder=outlook.Folders("mb data proc")`

needs to be

`folder=outlook.Folders.Item("mb data proc")`