# How to schedule meeting using non-default calendar?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

What is the property in an AppointmentItem (MeetingStatus = olMeeting), to change the Calendar I'm using to schedule a meeting?

It is using the default account no matter what. I need to alternate between accounts configured in Outlook.

I tested these properties:

```
.SendUsingAccount

.Organizer
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to additional Inbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Organizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862207.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the AppointmentItem class is read-only. So, the only possible way is to re-create appointment in the appropriate calendar/folder.

See [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) for possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an Outlook item in a non-default folder you need to use the Items.Add method for the Folder.Items collection in the folder where you want it created.  If that folder is a default folder in a non-default account, use Store.GetDefaultFolder.