# How to Create Task in Shared Task List?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to convert an email to task and place that task inside a shared task folder. My co-worker shared the folder and has given me owner access to the folder as well.

We have utilized the script on [slipstick](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/create-tasks-task-folders/) to accomplish this. This code does work for my co-worker, but does not work for me.

When I dig into the list of folders I see my personal task list as a folder and not the shared folder. (Via the code below)

Is there any way that I can add a task to a shared task folder?

```
Public strFolders As String
     
Public Sub GetFolderNames()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olSession As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olStartFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim lCountOfFound As Long
     
    lCountOfFound = 0
          
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olSession = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
          
    ' Allow the user to pick the folder in which to start the search.
    Set olStartFolder = olSession.PickFolder
          
    ' Check to make sure user didn't cancel PickFolder dialog.
    If Not (olStartFolder Is Nothing) Then
        ' Start the search process.
        ProcessFolder olStartFolder
    End If
         
    ' Create a new mail message with the folder list inserted
    Set ListFolders = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    ListFolders.Body = strFolders
    ListFolders.Display
          
    ' clear the string so you can run it on another folder
    strFolders = ""
End Sub
      
Sub ProcessFolder(CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
             
    Dim i As Long
    Dim olNewFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olTempFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olTempFolderPath As String
    ' Loop through the items in the current folder.
    For i = CurrentFolder.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
    
        Set olTempFolder = CurrentFolder.Folders(i)
              
        olTempFolderPath = olTempFolder.FolderPath
    
        ' Get the count of items in the folder
        olCount = olTempFolder.Items.Count
    
        'prints the folder path and name in the VB Editor's Immediate window
        Debug.Print olTempFolderPath & " " & olCount
               
        ' prints the folder name only
        ' Debug.Print olTempFolder
              
        ' create a string with the folder names.
        ' use olTempFolder if you want foldernames only
        strFolders = strFolders & vbCrLf & olTempFolderPath & " " & olCount
             
        lCountOfFound = lCountOfFound + 1
              
    Next
    ' Loop through and search each subfolder of the current folder.
    For Each olNewFolder In CurrentFolder.Folders
              
        'Don't need to process the Deleted Items folder
        If olNewFolder.Name <> "Deleted Items" Then
            ProcessFolder olNewFolder
        End If
              
    Next
          
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition the Task folder, you will need permission to your co-worker's Mailbox. (Not Inbox nor other folders.)

If you add the mailbox to your profile, see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox).

If you do not add the mailbox to your profile, see the answer describing [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32389928/1571407). Redemption is not required.