# Count Read and Unread Emails date wise for shared mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I have edited VBA which I found in Stack Overflow to suit my needs.

It gives me the count of emails of my default inbox date wise and count of unread emails without dates.

I need it to count the emails of my shared mailbox. For example Redstreamattmail and not the default mailbox, DATE WISE for overall emails and unread emails.

```
Sub HowManyEmails()    

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder    
Dim EmailCount As Integer    

Dim a As Outlook.Application    
Dim b As Outlook.NameSpace    
Dim c As Outlook.MAPIFolder    

Set a = New Outlook.Application    
Set b = a.GetNamespace("MAPI")    
Set c = b.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)    
d = c.UnReadItemCount    

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")    

On Error Resume Next    

Set objFolder = objnSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)    

If Err.Number <> 0 Then    
    Err.Clear    
    MsgBox "No such folder."    
    Exit Sub    
End If    

EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count    

MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount & " Total Unread     email count are   " & d    

Dim dateStr As String    
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items    
Dim dict As Object    
Dim msg, msg1 As String    

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")    
Set myItems = objFolder.Items    

myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")    

' Determine date of each message:    

For Each myItem In myItems    
    dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)    
    If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then    
        dict(dateStr) = 0    
    End If    
    dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1    
Next myItem    

' Output counts per day:    
For Each o In dict.Keys    
    msg = msg & o & ":    " & dict(o) & " Email items" & vbCrLf    
Next    
msg1 = "unread Emails are        " & d    

Set objFolder = Nothing    
Set objnSpace = Nothing    
Set objOutlook = Nothing    

'Send Email    
Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")    
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)    

With OutMail    
    .Subject = "Count of emails"    
    .To = "name@company.com;"    
    .Body = msg & msg1    
    .Display    
    '.Send    
End With     

Set OutMail = Nothing    
Set OutApp = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to additional Inbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Comment: Did you try debugging? set breakpoints, watch variables ... try add method on dict ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Set c =  b.Folders("Name of shared mailbox")
```

Where you put the correct folder name in there.

Comment: It worked for me thanks so much, but i noticed i am not getting correct count of emails each day in the mailbox for all emails, however unread email count i get it right. any edition i need to do to get the correct email count?

Comment: You can ask a new question so it is noticed. Include the code for GetDate. Not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796392/counting-emails-in-outlook-2010-in-specific-folder as there is no accepted answer to the incorrect count.

Comment: Can we do something so that email is prompted with only unread emails for each day?/

Comment: @Striker See advice posted in the second comment on this answer.  If you have a new question, please ask a new question so that it can be addressed.  [If I knew the answer off the top of my head, I'd probably tell you, but I answered this over 2 years ago and don't generally work with this anymore]