# Reference inbox of a different account

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am looking for a way to pull down the information of a different Outlook  account into an Excel spreadsheet.

The below code works only for my personal inbox:

```
Sub psinbox()
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oltaskfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oltask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim olitems As Outlook.Items

Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim x As Long
Dim arrheaders As Variant

Set olNs = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oltaskfolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olitems = oltaskfolder.Items

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlapp.Workbooks.Add

x = 2
arrheaders = Array("Date Created", "Date Recieved", "Subject", "Sender", 
"Senders Email", "CC", "Sender's Email Type", "MSG Size", "Unread?")
On Error Resume Next
xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrheaders)).Value = ""

Do
    With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
        If Not (olitems(x).Subject = "" And olitems(x).CreationTime = "") Then
            .Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrheaders) + 1) = arrheaders
            .Cells(x, 1).Value = olitems(x).CreationTime
            .Cells(x, 2).Value = olitems(x).recievedtime
            .Cells(x, 3).Value = olitems(x).Subject
            .Cells(x, 4).Value = olitems(x).SenderName
            .Cells(x, 6).Value = olitems(x).CC
            .Cells(x, 7).Value = olitems(x).SenderEmailType ' this is either internal or external server
            .Cells(x, 8).Value = Format((olitems(x).Size / 1024) / 1024, "#,##0.00") & " MB"
            .Cells(x, 9).Value = olitems(x).UnRead
            x = x + 1

        End If
    End With
Loop Until x >= olitems.Count + 1

Set olNs = Nothing
Set oltaskfolder = Nothing
Set olitems = Nothing

Set xlapp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

I want to record how many received emails are unread.

The closest I found was here [Count Read and Unread Emails date wise for shared mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583378/count-read-and-unread-emails-date-wise-for-shared-mailbox) , which mentioned that would need to Set c =  b.Folders("Name of shared mailbox"), however this appears to be for different folders inside the same mail account. What I am after though is access to two different accounts which outlook has access to?

**Edit:**

Having tried Niton's example, I am having an issue with the below.

```
If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set oltaskfolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, 
olFolderInbox).Folders("admin")
    Set olitems = oltaskfolder.Items
End If
```

I have tried to use the user name of the shared inbox, the email address, and the name of the email account, but all bring up the following error.

[image: Current Error]

Comment: If you do not have the mailbox in your profile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851850/vba-outlook-selecting-a-subfolder-in-the-sharedmailbox-using-getshareddefaultfol otherwise this is the another version of the question you found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Outlook Selecting a Subfolder in the SharedMailbox using GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851850/vba-outlook-selecting-a-subfolder-in-the-sharedmailbox-using-getshareddefaultfol)

Comment: The above is referring to sub folders rather than seperate mail accounts. However I will try the link in your first suggestion http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it seems was to remove a section which caused complications.

```
If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set oltaskfolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, 
olFolderInbox)
    Set olitems = oltaskfolder.Items
End If
```

Removing .Folders("admin") fixed the error that was coming up and solved the issue. It then gave me the information about the inbox exactly as required.

**Edit:**

Side note which I just found out, if you do want to have a sub folder in a shared mail box, just add the .Folders("mailbox") next to the olFolderInbox instead like below.

```
If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set oltaskfolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, 
olFolderInbox).Folders("mailbox")
    Set olitems = oltaskfolder.Items
End If
```

The previous pages did not work adding it next to CreateRecipient ??