# Outlook search emails with specific word in subject in non-default email folder

Tags: vba, outlook

Help please- I am a complete newbie at this - I have a folder called "Cel_Emails" at the same level as the default folders. It contains some emails  , and I manually do a search for all emails in this folder and look for all emails  containing the word "Example" in the subject line (at which point - it only shows those emails and hides all other emails in that folder).

I am trying to write a vba script to do this - but am failing miserably - can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a repeat question, this will get you started. [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

If you would like to know how to cycle through emails in a folder and open them based on a word in the subject i will edit my answer and post it below.

Comment: I really appreciate your helping - I tried to follow the thread you pointed me to - but I am failing. Bascially I am having trouble specifying the custom folder. My Cel_Emails folder is at teh top level and I am trying toa ccess it using :

Comment: I really appreciate your helping - I tried to follow the thread you pointed me to - but I am failing. Bascially I am having trouble specifying the custom folder. My Cel_Emails folder is at teh top level and I am trying to access it using :
Set Celfolder=Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Cel_Emails") - but I keep getting a type mismatch error. Can you please help and post a snippet that shows me _> if I have a folder called Cel_Emails" on the default level -and I want to do a search so that only the emails with "Example" in the subject line show (all others are masked) -

Comment: I am a little confused, is your, "Cel_Emails" a folder in your mailbox? or is it a whole separate mail box that has its own inbox and sent etc.