# Reference to non-default non-English inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying set a reference to a non-default inbox in MS Outlook. I have found [a code in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox),

```
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("Procurement, Request")
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
```

which is OK when inbox is named "Inbox".

There is a possibility for inboxes to be named in non-English languages.

You may refer to the default inbox by

```
objNS.getdefaultfolder(6)
```

But what about non-defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get inboxes by Store index or name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Inbox_by_Store()

Dim allStores As Stores
Dim storeInbox As Folder

Dim i As Long

Set allStores = Session.Stores

For i = 1 To allStores.count

    Debug.Print i & " DisplayName - " & allStores(i).DisplayName

    Set storeInbox = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set storeInbox = allStores(i).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not storeInbox Is Nothing Then
        storeInbox.Display
    End If

Next

ExitRoutine:
    Set allStores = Nothing
    Set storeInbox = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, what is Stores, should I add any reference to any library?

Comment: Code should run as is. What result did you get.

Comment: I can see. I've tried it from Excel, from Outlook it works perfectly. I think I can adapt it to my Excel VBA. Thank you very much.