# Access O365 group calendar folder in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to write a macro which would create an appointment in O365 group calendar.
I am able to create the appointment if the current folder is the group calender. However, I want the macro to always create the appointment for the group calendar, irrespective of the current folder.
I have looked at other posts on accessing shared calendar and other subfolders under default calendar, but I am not able to find anything that works for a group calender.

I have tried these things:

```
    ' option1
  Set calFolder = GetFolderPath("abc@email.com\Calendars\groupname")
  Set NameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' option 2
  Set calFolder = NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders("groupname")
  NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder("groupemail", olFolderCalendar)
  Set Items = calFolder.Items
  ' option 3  
  Set Items = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("groupname").Items
```

This is office 365 group. Lets call it abc. The group email is abc@somedoamin.com

In the folder structure it appear like this:

> My Mailbox
>
> > -Groups
> >
> > > --abc

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I found this structure for the group I am looking for in the debugger:

Namespace
|
AddressLists
|
 |
  Item 7 : Name: All groups
   |
   AddressEntries
    |
    Item 18: Name: abc

Is there a way I can use this information to get the folder?

[image: Screenshot of structure under namespace]

Comment: Edit the question to apply this advice [mcve]

Comment: Describe where the calendar appears in the folder tree. Perhaps a diagram similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox

Comment: Hi,
This is office 365 group. Lets call it abc. The group email is abc@somedoamin.com

In the folder structure it appear like this:
My Mailbox-
   -Groups
       ---abc

Also edited the question with this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GetSharedDefaultFolder`, but its first argument is a `Recipient` object, not a string. Call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` (passing a string), then pass that `Recipient` object to `GetSharedDefaultFolder`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried your approach. But now its giving me a runtime error:
"The server mailbox cannot be opened because this address book entry is not a mail user"

Comment: Does the same name work in Outlook if you click "File | Open | Other User's Folder"?

Comment: Here you go. Exchange is telling you there is no mailbox that belongs to the specified name. Is that the name of a distribution list?

Comment: But it does have a mailbox. It has shared mailbox and has its own calendar too.
Office 365 groups are different than distribution lists.
I am able to send and receive emails and create events on this calendar.
I have updated the question with the folder structure

Comment: Groups, even if they are exposed in the Outlook UI, are not (at least yet) exposed through OOM or even MAPI - on the MAPI level, there is a store, but it is not in the session stores table.

Comment: Ohh. Well that's a bummer! I will stick to my original code then. Thank you!