# How to import emails from outlook into excel document when it is a shared email inbox

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, shared

I am new to writing code and am not sure how to go from the default inbox which is mine to a shared email inbox.

```
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Appointments")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try : [getshareddefaultfolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder)

```
Dim OutNS As Outlook.Namespace
Set Folder = OutNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
```