# Selecting inbox when multiple exist

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi I am using the following macro to create a batch of new folders in an inbox. It performs fantastically however I can't for the life of me figure out how to select a different inbox (inbox1, inbox2, inbox3) all different email accounts.

code is here: http://www.slipstick.com/macros/Create%20subfolders%20at%20multiple%20levels.txt

Comment: Please don't post links to the code. Instead include the code within your question. Links may disappear after a while and the question gets useless to future readers. According [ask] and [help] everthing that is needed to understand the question (including code) needs to be within the question itself. Please [edit] your question and include the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Session.GetDefaultFolder`, call `Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` / `Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder`

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply to me, i am extremely new to coding would you be willing to show an example of the solution?

Comment: See example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder

Answer (score 0):

If all these inboxes are configured in Outlook you can use the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.stores) collection to iterate over stores and using the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument.

If you need to access shared mailboxes you need to use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If
End Sub
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```