# Select folders in different mailboxes

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to collect email count data from Outlook using Excel VBA. In addition to my personal email, I have access to other mailboxes account/stores(?). The labels on the Outlook mailbox/accounts are `HR`,`Marketing`, `Accounting`. I'd like to loop through the folders in these mailboxes/stores and perform some task.

A for loop through `Sessions.Accounts`, only accesses my default mailbox (i.e. not `HR`,`Marketing`,`Accounting`). It looks like I can access my non-default mailboxes if I loop through `Session.Stores`:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    
    For Each acct In olApp.Session.Stores
        MsgBox acct
    'how can I access folders and emails within these Stores?
End Sub
```

This returns message boxes with `HR`, `Marketing`, `Accounting`. I am not able to select the inbox or other folders within these non-default mailboxes though.

For my default mailbox, I was able to get it:

```vb
Sub default_email_count()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olbNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("sample_folder")
    
    Count = olFolder.Items.Count
    Msgbox Count
    'this code successfully outputs the count of emails in my default mailbox within the folder "sample folder"
```

How can I extend the above code to work across other `Stores` and not just my default mailbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows how to enumerate all folders on all stores for an Outlook session.

1. The code sample begins by getting all the stores for the current session using the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property of the current session, `Application.Session`.
2. For each store of this session, it uses [Store.GetRootFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getrootfolder) to obtain the folder at the root of the store.
3. For the root folder of each store, it iteratively calls the `EnumerateFolders` procedure until it has visited and displayed the name of each folder in that tree.

```
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores 
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders 
  
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
  
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
   Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the mailboxes are already in your profile, use the `Namespace.Stores` collection. Default folders can be accessed using `Store.GetDefaultFolder` (instead of `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`).

You can also use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` - it takes `Recipient` object as one of its parameters (you can get it from `Namespace.CreateRecipient`).