# Move Shared Mailbox Email To Folder When Category Assigned

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script that works on my main inbox. It will move the email to a sub folder when a category is assigned. The sub folder is the same name as the category.

How do I modify the code to reference a shared mailbox?

My code that works on main inbox:

```vb
Private WithEvents xInboxFld As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents xInboxItems As Outlook.Items
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set xInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set xInboxItems = xInboxFld.Items
End Sub
 
Private Sub xInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xFlds As Outlook.Folders
Dim xFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xTargetFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xFlag As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Set xMailItem = Item
    xFlag = False
    If xMailItem.Categories <> "" Then
        Set xFlds = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
        If xFlds.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each xFld In xFlds
                If xFld.Name = xMailItem.Categories Then
                    xFlag = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If xFlag = False Then
            Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders.Add xMailItem.Categories, olFolderInbox
        End If
        Set xTargetFld = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(xMailItem.Categories)
        xMailItem.Move xTargetFld
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working with the below

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents SharedInboxFld As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents SharedInboxItems As Outlook.Items
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set SharedInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.Folders.Item("Shared MailboxName").Folders("Inbox")  'use the appropriate folder name
    Set SharedInboxItems = SharedInboxFld.Items
End Sub


Private Sub SharedInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim xFlds As Outlook.Folders
Dim xFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xTargetFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xFlag As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        xFlag = False
        If Item.Categories <> "" Then
            Set xFlds = SharedInboxFld.Folders
            If xFlds.Count <> 0 Then
                For Each xFld In xFlds
                    If xFld.Name = Item.Categories Then
                        xFlag = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            If xFlag = False Then
                SharedInboxFld.Folders.Add Item.Categories, olFolderInbox
            End If
            Set xTargetFld = SharedInboxFld.Folders(Item.Categories)
            Item.Move xTargetFld
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please consider providing a short summary as to what you fixed and why it was wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that will only work if the mailbox in question is open and visible in your profile. `GetSharedDefaultFolder` will work in all cases as long as you have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GetDefaultFolder`, call `Outlook.Application.Session.CreateRecipient`, and pass the returned `Recipient` object to `GetSharedDefaultFolder`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I have been trying to figure out how to implement your suggestion in the above code and still scratching my head. Do I only do this in the "Private Sub Application_Startup()" ? Do you have an example you could share with me?