# How to connect to Generic Mailbox Inbox and subfolders?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I have code to connect my default inbox in outlook.

I am not able to connect to a generic mailbox inbox. Please could someone review the code and help on this issue.

```vb
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim eFolder As Outlook.folder '~~> additional declaration
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
Dim olRecip As Recipient
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Date, ws As Worksheet '~~> declare WS variable instead
Dim lrow As Long '~~> additional declaration
Dim collItems As New Collection
Dim MovecollItems As New Collection

Set ws = ActiveSheet '~~> or you can be more explicit using the next line
Set EC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email Search Criteria")
Set IE = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inbox Emails")
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)'ABC.com "My default Email Folder"

Set Inbox_1 = olNs.Folders("ch-heaphq05test@xyz.com").Folders("Inbox") 'Problem is over here.
'Set IB_SubFolder = Inbox_1.Folders("Inbox")
'Set RE_SubFolder = Inbox_1.Folders("Rejected Emails")

[![enter image description here][1]][1]  

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv5uA.png
```

Comment: Do you mean a shared mailbox? What exactly do you mean saying `generic mailbox`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get reference to additional Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/get-reference-to-additional-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right to access the mailbox and folder in question, use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` instead of `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder` above.